# Remove empty divs with tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got some tables nested in divs, and some of them are empty, or contain a space, or contain single character like "-", and I call it **EMPTY DIVs**. How can I remove the **EMPTY DIVs** descriped above using JavaScript when loading the document?

Part of my **EMPTY DIVs** is like this

```
<div class="extra">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="extra">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>-</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: has your div got a class or id?

Comment: Yes! But due to the bulk adding of divs, their classes are the same.

Comment: @Darklizard are you using jQuery library on this site ?

Comment: @rab yes I include it.

Comment: @Darklizard I have added an answer using jQuery .. Why you not post code that you tried ? seems question got lot of negative votes .. without posting `your code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.extra').filter(function(){
    var text = $.trim($(this).find('table').text());
    return text == '' || text == '-';
}).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cj2gJ/)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var $emptyDivs = $();

$('div table').each( function(){
    // getting table text, replaced with space
    var c = $(this).text().replace(/\s/g,'');
    // add condition for empty check 
    if ( c =='' || c == '-'){
       // add parent div
       $emptyDivs.push( $(this).closest('div')[0] );
    }
});

// remove empty div
$emptyDivs.remove();
```

Hope this will helps ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

you can use `$('#yourdivid').text()` to get the values of the div, compare with the values you want and use the below method to delete the divs.

```
var rdiv = document.getElementById('yourdivid');
    rdiv.parentNode.removeChild( rdiv );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".extra").find("table").each(function(){  
   if( $.trim($(this).find("tr td").text()) == "" || $.trim($(this).find("tr td").text()) == "-" )
      {
        $(this).parents(".extra:first").remove();
      }

});
```